# What does this LINQ do?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I am trying to learn LINQ query expressions. In MS website, I found this LINQ query.

```
public void Linq16() 
{ 
   List<Customer> customers = GetCustomerList();   
   var orders = 
       from c in customers 
       from o in c.Orders 
       where o.OrderDate >= new DateTime(1998, 1, 1) 
       select new { c.CustomerID, o.OrderID, o.OrderDate };   
  ObjectDumper.Write(orders); 
}
```

I am not sure what that c.Orders does. I visualized customers and orders like  data tables. Can someone tell me what this c.Orders does and what is it called?

Comment: That's a foreign key.

Comment: Its a related entity, set by entity framework that uses the foreign key to know its relationships*

Comment: Please advise why this question has been down voted

Answer (score 3):

It means that the entity `Customer` has a related entity, namely `Order`. The table might look like:

### Order

- OrderID
- OrderData
- CustomerID **(this is a Foreign Key to the Customer table)**

### Customer

- CustomerID
- Name
- ...

The **Entity Framework** will recognize the relationship between the two tables and create classes, **similar** to following:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set;}

    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

To understand the code a little more, the double `from` could be rewritten as:

```
foreach(Customer c in customers)
{
    foreach(Order o in c.Orders)
    {
        if(o.OrderDate >= new DateTime(1998, 1, 1))
        {
            yield return new { c.CustomerID, o.OrderID, o.OrderDate };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: spot on. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT LINQ, but LINQ to entities.

Its a related entity. Basically its another table, and you can use it through including it.

When doing it with sql, you would have to select the table by the foreign key, EF does that automatically for you.

What you're doing there is the same as Include: [MSDN blog example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx).
`Include()` is the Method syntax of the part of the query you dont understand.

Entity Framework creates a list of items of the other table as member of your entity - which is weird in the first place (just unusual actually) but very very useful, since you can `ToList()` the entity and they will be included if you `.Include()` them before.

To be very exact, you have a List (or something similar to list) added to the customer object (this is done by entity framework) and every Order is a line in the Orders table.

**If you do want to use linq, but not Entity Framework, ignore it and search for other sources to learn linq.**

Here is a really good resource to learn: [MSDN, 101 LINQ examples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)